# How to enforce classes to follow a contract to define a DB-insert statement?

Tags: java, jdbc

My question is a conceptual one as I really lack experience in this field.

The situation is as follows:

I have a database which right now contains 2 tables, but I am not sure if in the future there will follow other tables and I will have to write different readers that transform data from different file-formats/data-dumps into corresponding java-objects and prepare it to be inserted into the DB.

I thought it would be nice to enforce my java-classes, that have a representation in form of a table, to contain a method `createPreparedStatementInsert(...)` (or similar) which returns a JDBC `PreparedStatement` to insert data into the corresponding table.

In my thought this method would have to be static, because otherwise I would have to generate a separate prepared statement for any object I want to insert into the table which nullifies the use of the prepared statement as my intention is to generate it one time only and then reuse it to batch-add a lot of data (from whatever parsing process of some external file).

But static methods in an interface are not enforced on the implementing class at compile time.

So: how would I do that without loosing the correctness-check at compile-time?

I hope it is understandable what I am trying to achieve.

If the idea itself is the wrong approach to this problem, feel free to tell me. I have read enough questions on SO where the main outcome was that OP tried to solve the wrong problem and I am happy to learn better ways.

Comment: Don't go down this road. Look into using ORM like Hibernate or tools like MyBatis or jOOQ. Also: using static prepared statements is asking for problems if you are going to need parallel processing (each thread should use their own connection, or otherwise carefully synchronize access). In any case, this is far too vague and broad to really be able to address with a solid and specific answer.

Comment: What "correctness-checks" are you actually trying to enforce compile-time? Any solution that uses plain JDBC would suffer from the same problem: that the SQL queries wouldn't be type safe. Using tools like JPA with Criteria API / QueryDSL or Jooq would solve this problem. However, these could be a bit overkill in a small project. Adding good coverage of integration testing with DBUnit gives you confidence if compile-time checking is hard to achieve.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies! I will try to improve my architecture. I was initially thinking about teaching myself some hibernate in this context but I got the advice from my advisor at the university (it's part of a project for my studies) that this would probably be an overkill. Concerning "correctness-check": I wanted to ensure that an abstract object is able to tell me how it has to be inserted into its corresponding db-table by having an interface like "DBWritable" or something like that; that was the initial idea but I will rework that after your comments.